# Node express static with csrf

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I'm trying to use `csurf` in nodejs, express and React Project. My csurf is working fine right now, but I want to double check if I did it right.

Here is my nodejs router and middleware structure:

```
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/...") // routes that don't need csrf

app.use("/form/...",csrf({cookie:true})) // form path with csrf middleware

app.use(express.static("/img")) // image folder which doesn't need csrf

app.use(csrf({ cookie: true })); // enable csrf for the rest of the app 
app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("X-CSRF-Token", req.csrfToken()); // set csrf to header
  return next();
});

app.use(express.static("/SPA")); // frontend project
```

**Current behavior:**

1. When I first enter my web project, I have `X-CSRF-Token: xxxxx` and `set-cookie: _csrf=yyyyy; Path=/` in my `response headers`
2. When I refresh my page, `Cookie: _csrf=yyyyy;` appears in the `request headers` section.
3. When I refresh my page, `X-CSRF-Token` changes to a different value.
4. Only `X-CSRF-Token` value passed through post request, `_csrf` value inside cookie throw 403.

**Question:**

A. I believe setting `app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))` is redundant, but when I set it to false or removed `app.all(...)` part, the app throw 403 / Internal Server Error. How to fix it?

B. `X-CSRF-Token` changes everytime I refreshed my page, it's obviously a normal behavior since I put it in the header, but does it defeat the purpose of csrf? Since my project is SPA, do I really care that much?

Please point out if there were anything wrong with the logic / behavior ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Since my project is SPA, do I really care that much?

If a client app (SPA or not) sends some data to the backend and the data changes backend's state either directly or indirectly, for example via an action performed by backend on client's behalf, then CSRF vulnerability exists and you should care unless SPA framework like Angular takes care of CSRF protection. Using SPA doesn't change anything with respect to CSRF, it doesn't help and it alleviates nothing.

With cookie-parser middleware the csrf middleware works like that:

- Checks for its cookie with a predefined name in the incoming request. If not found then generates a secret key and puts its value (decorated a bit) into the response cookie hoping to find it in the next request. So the secret is not a secret anymore.
- If cookie not found and the incoming request is mutating like POST (e.g. not GET, HEAD ...) then fail it e.g. send 403 back with cookie set. If non-mutating like GET then processing is finished.
- If cookie found then check for the *second piece of data*, by default in few places including HTTP header with a predefined name. If not found or found and incorrect then fail incoming request. Otherwise processing is finished.

To ensure this check is successful you are responsible for 2 steps:
- on the backend call `req.csrfToken()` to obtain this *second piece of data* and store in the response. You have chosen to store it in HTTP header, it's fine. But you could have used any header name. Or you could have used `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` section.
- on the client take the *second piece of data* from the above header or `<meta>` tag in the backend response and put it into the request you are about to send assuming the request is mutating e.g. POST, PUT, etc. Furthermore, you need to put it into one of the predefined places in the request where csrf middleware [searches](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#value) by default.

Regarding your code:
1. The client code responsible for the second step is missing.
2. On the backend call `csrf({options})` function once and store the returned value. You have called it twice. The return value, let's call it `retValue`, is the configured csrf middleware, use it as needed:
 `app.post(/<path>, retValue, ...req, res, next) => {...`
3. As for the options, set `httpOnly: true`. Additionally, in production set `secure: true`:

```js
csrf({cookie: {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true
}})
```

Comment: Thanks, correctly me if I'm wrong, I configured my POST method to use jwt-token, and the token was stored in localStorage/sessionStorage but not inside **cookies**, then I don't really need to worry about CSRF right?

Comment: @SOF_Sucks The POST method posts some data. If this data changes some state on the server (e.g. is stored on the server, used now or later somehow e.g. to change some database) then one should worry about CSRF no matter what tokens are used to post the data and where on the client the tokens are stored. Unless the documentation on your framework says it ensures CSRF protection.

Answer (score 1):

> A. I believe setting `app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))` is redundant,
>   but when I set it to false or removed `app.all(...)` part, the app
>   throw 403 / Internal Server Error. How to fix it?

By setting `app.use(csrf{cookie:true})` before your routes you tell your app to pass each request that you get through csrf middleware (except those higher than this command). This middleware is supposed to do 3 things.

First is to set csrf cookie, if it's not present yet. This cookie is a secret which is needed to create/verify csrf tokens.

Second is to create new token when you call `req.csrfToken()`.

Third is to verify tokens for all non-GET/HEAD/OPTION requests.

Also it's important to understand what you do with this command:

> app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {   res.header("X-CSRF-Token",
>   req.csrfToken()); // set csrf to header   return next(); });

All your requests (get, post, put etc etc) they generate new token on the basis of the secret you have in your cookie. Same secret generates random tokens, as random salts are used for this purpose.

So in case you remove app.all part with `req.csrfToken()` you will not be generating any tokens, so verification will fail. And in case you remove `app.use(csrf)` part you will not be able to verify anything as this part does verification and you will fail to issue tokens as well. Because in other words the middleware will be turned off. So you can't remove any of these two commands as they serve different purpose.

> B. X-CSRF-Token changes everytime I refreshed my page, it's obviously a normal behavior since I put it in the header, but does it defeat the purpose of csrf? Since my project is SPA, do I really care that much?

The purpose of csrf tokens is to verify whether request came from your website, because otherwise the client will have cookie only, but no token in the header. Pressing link initiating some actions on your website, but being on a different website will not generate csrf token for the client.